# Confused about behavior of ?. operator

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code

```
class Address
{
    public bool IsAppartment { get; set; }
}

class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}    
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee()
        {
            Name = "Charlie"
        };
        if (employee.Address?.IsAppartment ?? true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Its an apartment");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No employee address or not an apartment");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program

> Its an apartment

According to the definition of [?.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) operator

> if one operation in a chain of conditional member or element access
>   operations returns null, the rest of the chain doesn't execute.

In this case, Address object is null, I don't understand why it's not going in the else branch of the code here?

**UPDATE**
What will be equivalent code for following using short cut operators?

```
if (employee.Address != null && employee.Address.IsAppartment == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Its an apartment");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No employee address or not an apartment");
}
```

Comment: The `??` after evaluates it to `true` - [?? operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: If `Adress` is null the result will be `null` as well. The `??` operator sees it's null and uses the value specified instead. Here that value is `true` so it of course doesn't go into the `else` branch.

Comment: Seems like you just need to use `?? false` instead so that no address info will drop to the else.

Comment: You have three choices here.  One is that employee.Address is null.  The other two choices are based on assuming that the address is not null, and the IsAppartment flag is true or false.  Given your WriteLine strings, what you probably want is 'if (employee.Address.?IsAppartment ?? false)`.  What that says is "If the address is null, assume false, otherwise, if it's not null, read the IsAppartment property and return its value (true or false).

Comment: By the way, you don't need to have `someBooleanExpression == true` in an if statement.  The `someBooleanExpression` is true or false all on its own, it doesn't need a comparison to true.  Then again, if you feel more comfortable (or it makes more sense to your eyes/head), I'm pretty sure that the optimizer will get rid of it for you under the covers

Comment: @Flydog57 Without uisng == true in that expression, I get a compilation error about converting bool? to bool

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Since that expression can be true/false or null, under the covers it is of type `Nullable<bool>` (aka `bool?`).  It doesn't have intrinsic true-ness/false-ness, since it has a third possible state.  Oops.

Comment: Please check the MSDN,
?: operator - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator ??: operator - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator hope it will help you.. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is correct, the rest of the chain doesn't execute, null-coalescing operator `??` returns `true`. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

> The null-coalescing operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand
>   operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand
>   operand and returns its result.

If you want to compare the result with either `true` or `false` (per your update) you can use

```
if (employee?.Address?.IsAppartment == true)
{
}
```

The left-hand operand returns `Nullable<bool>`, you can also read about it in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

Comment: I have updated my question with the code I am trying to use the shortcut for. Can you suggest what I am doing wrong there?

Answer (score 8):

> **UPDATE** What will be equivalent code for following using short cut operators?
>   `if (employee.Address != null && ? employee.Address.IsAppartment == true)`

```
if (employee?.Address?.IsAppartment == true)
```